# VS 2015 Team Explorer default browser

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

Whenever I initiate a Pull Request in Visual Studio 2015, the page is being opened in Internet Explorer even though Google Chrome is set as my default browser in VS (for debugging)

Where is the setting to have my TFS/Git actions performed in Chrome also rather than IE?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the Chrome as default browser in Chrome setting. I have tested on my side, once you set Chrome as default browser in Chrome setting, the web page will be opened in Chrome by defatul.

[image]